# How do I send event_id with Facebook pixel?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I get an error from Facebook:

> #### Purchase Event Missing Some Deduplication Parameters You're sending
>
> Purchase events through both your pixel and the Conversions API, but
> they're not being deduplicated properly because not enough of these
> events are receiving an event_id parameter. Event instances sent
> without an event_id parameter cannot be deduplicated.
>
> Add an event_id parameter to all Purchase events that you're sending
> from both your pixel and the Conversions API. To add an event_id
> parameter to the events you're sending through the Conversions API,
> you can use the Payload Helper tool on the Facebook for Developers
> site to validate that your payload is set up correctly. To add an
> event_id parameter to the events you're sending through your pixel, go
> into your website's source code and add an event_id parameter to each
> of your Purchase event instances.

But I am sending event_id in my pixel event for Purchase!

Answer (score 23):

The correct way to send event_id on the server **with the [Conversions API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api)** is at the same level as `event_name` and not inside `user_data` or `custom_data`.

**However with the pixel** on the client you need to send it like this **as a fourth parameter** to fbq.

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: 12, currency: 'USD'}, {eventID: 'purchase.123456'});
```

Note it is named `eventID` [when sent from pixel](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/deduplicate-pixel-and-server-events) and not `event_id`. (Despite the actual error message referring to it as `event_id`). At time of writing this was the only page in which I could find this third parameter mentioned.

You can verify in the events manager tool by clicking 'View Details' for an event and then looking at 'Event Deduplication'. It will confirm the parameter is received from the pixel. It may not show here for several hours, or even until the next day - even if you're seeing events being received in real time.

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I find the event_id for AddToCart and other events? Currently I'm sending the requests to conversion API without event_id parameter.

Comment: It can be whatever you want! You just need to send the SAME ID on the client and server to represent the same AddToCart event. You could do something simple to start like `const event_id = 'ATC_' + new Date().getTime();` and send that value to both APIs. Unless you are running Amazon.com you probably don't have two people adding to cart the same millisecond - but add a session id or other random number to be sure. Another way would be to call your server to log the event and return a server generated ID which you then pass to Facebook's API - if you do this make sure it returns quickly.

Comment: What if you do not have a 3rd parameter? Do you just pass empty curly braces {} ? Also, can you send eventId with a PageView event type?

Comment: I would imagine either null or {} would be equally fine in that case.

Comment: There's this example in the documentation where `{}` is passed when you don't have anything to pass in the third parameter: `fbq('track', 'Lead', {}, {eventID: 'EVENT_ID'});` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/deduplicate-pixel-and-server-events/)

Answer (score 1):

I am implementing `Facebook C.API` with `GTM` (maybe it is not useful for you) using different values for `eventID`, for `AddToCart` external cookie IDs, as it is recommended on their documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/server-event#event-id

The `transaction_ID` for `InitiateCheckout` and `Purchase` event. A good idea could be use the Facebook `Ad-ID`.

However, `event_id` and `event_name` are the **strongest recommendation**, not the only one.
You can use others as long as **they are unique for that event**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).